# Cannot send `--` into tmux panes from vim

Tags: tmux

I've the following function and accompanying key-bindings to send texts from vim in one tmux pane to other:

```
" copy yanked text to tmux pane
function! Send_to_tmux(count) abort
    let _count = (a:count == 0) ? 2 : a:count
    let text = @z
    let text = substitute(text, ';', '\\;', 'g')
    let text = substitute(text, '"', '\\"', 'g')
    let text = substitute(text, '\n', '" Enter "', 'g')
    let text = substitute(text, '!', '\\!', 'g')
    let text = substitute(text, '%', '\\%', 'g')
    let text = substitute(text, '#', '\\#', 'g')
    silent execute "!tmux send-keys -t " . _count . " \"" . text . "\""
    silent execute "!tmux send-keys -t " . _count . "Enter"
    unlet _count
    unlet text
endfunction
nnoremap <expr> <Leader>p '"zyip:call Send_to_tmux('.v:count.')<CR>'
xnoremap <expr> <Leader>p '"zy:call Send_to_tmux('.v:count.')<CR>'
```

I basically use this function when I use SQL. Now, SQL has commenting structure of two types:
<sup>(written in the structure of `:h 'commentstring'`)</sup>

- /* %s */
- -- %s

I always used the first type of comment, and didn't set up the substitute command for second type of comment. And now I see that I can't send texts into other tmux panes of structure `-- texts`. I have tried it in bare bash, and MySQL command line, same result. So, I guess bash is not taking string of that structure, or tmux is eating it itself.

I've removed all tmux configurations and tried to do it, same result. So, I don't think it's a problem with my tmux config.

How do I send `--` to tmux panes from vim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks more like a shell related question than a Vim related question. I would try the following  (not tested, so might be wrong):

```
silent execute "!tmux send-keys -t " . _count . " -- \"" . text . "\""
```

Add a `--` before the text. Most Unix commands stop option processing as soon as they see a `--` and everything after it is handled as parameter.

Comment: It worked! Sorry, I couldn't figure out where to actually post this question, i.e. Unix or Stackoverflow. And can I just change the mapping, i.e. always send ` -- ` before sending the text, irrespective of whether the text has `--` inside itself? I'm currently doing that, no problem yet occurred. If you have any comment, please let me know.

Comment: @klaus if, as Ralf describes, the SQL cli youre using is well-behaved under unix, it should work if you just always send `--` before your literal input

Comment: In particular, the SQL CLI should conform to Guideline 10 of the [Utility Syntax Guidelines (IEEE Std 1003.1-2001, Section 12.2)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap12.html#tag_12_02).